# Analytic isomorphism of Du Val singularities

Tags: algebraic-geometry, singularity

The standard equations for Du Val singularities are:

$$
A_{n}: x^2+y^2+z^{n+1} =0  \ (n \geq 1)
$$
and
$$
D_{n}: x^2+y^2z+z^{n-1}=0 \ (n \geq 4)
$$

So I wonder how to construct the isomorphism between $A_3$ and $D_3$ ?,
Here $D_3 $ is $x^2+y^2z+z^2=0$.

Also, $D_4$ is always written as $x^2+y^3+z^3=0$, why it is isomorphic to $x^2+y^2z+z^3=0$?

Comment: $D_3$ is $x^2+y^2z+z^2=0$

Comment: you should add your comment into original question by editing

Comment: You can get pretty far in answering this question with a little substitution of polynomials. What have you tried?

Comment: Thank you. I read notes of Miles Reid carefully and now I know how to construct it by change of variable

Comment: If you've figured it out, I'd suggest writing an answer to your own question so that others can learn from this in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $D_3\cong A_3$, if $x^2+y^2z+z^2=0$, just take $a=x, \ b=z+\frac{1}{2}y^2, \ c=\frac{i+1}{2}y\ $ ,$\ $ you can see $a^2+b^2+c^4=0$.

This idea is from $(y^2+z)^2 = y^4+2y^2z+z^2$

For two forms of $D_4$, if $x^2+y^2z+z^3=0$, take $a=x,\ b=2^{-1/3}z+3^{-1/2}\cdot 2^{-1/3}y,\ c=2^{-1/3}z-3^{-1/2}\cdot 2^{-1/3}y$ , $\ $
you can see that $a^2+b^3+c^3=0$.

And this idea is from the equation $(x+y)^3+(x-y)^3=2x^3+6xy^2$